# Consume blanket.js coverage reports in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, mocha.js, code-coverage, blanket.js

I have a node.js project running mocha tests, and I'm generating a coverage report using blanket.  I've managed to get the coverage report generated, but I'm not sure how to generate a report that can be consumed by and viewed in Jenkins.  Any suggestions?  I'm looking for a result similar to the Cobertura plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cobertura+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Sorry i misread your question, if the coverage report gets published with the xunit report i dont know. So the following might not help you.

---

The XUnit reporter should create a report that can be parsed by jenkins.

Check out [this](https://blog.dylants.com/2013/06/21/jenkins-and-node/) blog post.

---

Also, have a look into the [XUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin), it allows to specify the parser for various kinds of report formats.

[image]

---

Quote for persistence:
[image: Source https://blog.dylants.com/2013/06/21/jenkins-and-node/]
Source https://blog.dylants.com/2013/06/21/jenkins-and-node/